# Mysql query cant run in mssql

Tags: php, sql-server

This query runs well in mysql but cannot run in mssql. Why?

Don't judge me, I am new in mssql.

```
UPDATE cvcolumnlist
    SET columnindex=columnindex+1
    WHERE cvid=40 AND columnindex>=3
ORDER BY columnindex DESC
```

Error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
```

Comment: Why do you need order in an UPDATE statement ? Remove ORDER ..

Comment: A question solved in a single comment (Mihai lorga).

Comment: Oh cool, I am using vtiger, and trying to port it to mssql thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to remove ORDER clause. ORDER is pointless in an UPDATE statement.

```
UPDATE cvcolumnlist
    SET columnindex=columnindex+1
    WHERE cvid=40 AND columnindex>=3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE cvcolumnlist 
SET columnindex = columnindex+1 
WHERE cvid = 40 
    AND columnindex > 2
```

this should work

Answer (score 1):

You don't need at all the ORDER BY clause. this is only when `SELECT`ing data from the database.

You may want to note that even though SQL is a language with a specified structure, different SQL engines may parse the query differently and use different syntax since a lot of the SQL functionality is not defined by the language.

for example in mysql you may use the `LIMIT` keyword for limiting the number of records that are returned and in mssql you may use `ROWNUMBER` and oracle uses the `ROWNUM` system.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [cvcolumnlist]
SET [columnindex] = [columnindex] + 1
WHERE [cvid] = 40 AND [columnindex] >= 3
```

I'm not sure if this applies. Most of my queries use something like this.

```
UPDATE [database].[dbo].[cvcolumnlist]
SET [columnindex] = [columnindex] + 1
WHERE [cvid] = 40 AND [columnindex] >= 3
```